# preg_split not separating under certain conditions

Tags: php, preg-split, csv

I have a string of filenames coming from an API, there are 2 ways they are separated, one with a comma and also one with a comma then space but they are not mixed, for instance see the following

```
file name.png, filename2.png, filename3.png, filename4.png
```

or

```
filename.png,filename.png,file name.png,filename.png
```

I have been using the following code to create an array of filenames so far

```
$fileArray = preg_split( '/(\s|,|, )/', $fileList );
```

But, ive run into a problem where if i have a space in the filename, it chops it up.

Is there any way i can create an array of filenames which also include spaces in the filename?

Comment: Are you allowed to remove the spaces from the filenames in the string? If so, you could use `trim()`, and then just check against the comma. Otherwise, you'd need a fairly complex regex.

Comment: @ObsidianAge Hey, I can't modify the output of the string unfortunately

Comment: "also one with a space then comma" but your example shows comma then a space, which is it?  Is the separator actually, comma optionally followed by a space?

Comment: @salathe sorry, my bad, i've updated the question

Comment: In that case, your regex can be `/, ?/` (i.e. comma followed by zero or one space).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you really need regular expressions here:

```
$fileNames = explode(',', $fileList);
$fileArray = array_map('trim', $fileNames);
```

If you're looping through the array later in your code, skip the `array_map` and trim the file names inside your loop. That'll save an iteration.

Comment: Ahhh now why didnt i think of this ... I think i was too caught up in the preg_split world ... Thank you so much

Comment: @BigJobbies happens to the best of us :)

Answer (score 2):

If the delimiters are:

1. All comma-separated or
2. All comma-space-separated

You can just run a `strpos()` check and explode using the appropriate delimiter.

Code with 2 test runs: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/1b44ff81031a453f3321d329021c8b07e6ffc82e))

```
$fileLists=[
    'filename.png,file name2.png,filename3.png,filename4.png',
    'filename5.png, filename6.png, file name7.png, filename8.png'
];
foreach($fileLists as $fileList){
    var_export(explode(strpos($fileList,', ')!==false?", ":",",$fileList));
}
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 'filename.png',
  1 => 'file name2.png',
  2 => 'filename3.png',
  3 => 'filename4.png',
)array (
  0 => 'filename5.png',
  1 => 'filename6.png',
  2 => 'file name7.png',
  3 => 'filename8.png',
)
```

This means no iterated function calls to modify/clean each element).

...but honestly, I'd be using `preg_split('/, ?/',$fileList)` if this was my project because this is the shortest, most refined, literal method.

Comment: Upvoting the only answer making use of that information - that we have either of two formats.

Comment: Why not just use `explode(',', $fileNames)` and just use `trim` instead.

Comment: @Bluetree Because that is less efficient.  You would be iterating every element and calling trim() each time.

Comment: @mickmackusa What if there is more than one space `,  `? In this case you will create another condition which is not good. Using `trim()` is the better option for this.

Comment: That is beyond the scope of this page/question.  The OP clearly defines that there are only two types of delimiters.  If it was more variable, I would lean more and more toward regex -- because that is what it is for.  If one of the filenames starts with a space, my method will not damage it and `trim()` would (that's if we are putting our tinfoil hats on and generating fictitious fringe cases).  I have a better than average grip on regex.  I know if we are matching literal spaces, then ` ` is suitable, if we are matching tabs and newlines too, then `\s` is better.  I know about quantifiers.

Comment: @mickmackusa I understand. Thanks!.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. What you want is a separation of a comma **with or without** a space:

```
preg_split('/,\\s*/', $list);
```

You can support different separators:

```
preg_split('/[;,]\\s*/', $list);
```

Comment: Why are you escaping the whitespace character? and why write a pattern to include non-existent delimiters?

Comment: The whitespace is \s to the PCRE , but \ by itself needs escaping. Both \s and \\s work because \s would be an illegal escape, but I feel that \\s is more consistent. And I added a possible extra separator because it might be useful to others. If I felt otherwise, I might just as well delete any answer of mine that was not accepted as soon as another answer was.

Comment: @LSerni I had to lookup the usage of `\\s` as I've never used it myself, the same PCRE syntax applies for slashes. e.g. /\\\\\/ = \, due to the way PHP reads the slashes in strings. Our answers are virtually the same (aside from the multiple delimiters), Where `\s?` is an optional single white-space, as opposed to `\s*` meaning 0 or more. Which could be considered erroneous in case of malformed data. e.g.. `,\s\s` Technically I would use `\040` or `/ /` as a literal space character, but I used `\s` in my answer as it is more widely known than `\040` and more legible than `/ /`.

Answer (score 1):

To provide a regular expression solution, you would make the space an optional token by utilizing the `?`. 
The following regex will work with commas only, or a comma followed by a space, and allow for spaces within the non-delimited strings.

```
preg_split('/,\s?/', $string);
```

Results: https://3v4l.org/j87Qs

```
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  string(12) "filename.png"
  [1]=>
  string(12) "filename.png"
  [2]=>
  string(12) "filename.png"
  [3]=>
  string(12) "filename.png"
  [4]=>
  string(13) "file name.png"
}
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  string(12) "filename.png"
  [1]=>
  string(13) "filename2.png"
  [2]=>
  string(13) "filename3.png"
  [3]=>
  string(13) "filename4.png"
  [4]=>
  string(14) "file name5.png"
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what this function is to be used for.  Regex is sensibly used to avoid writing convoluted and/or otherwise unnecessarily complicated methods.